# Android: onItemClick()'s position is relative to viewable area, not entire list

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener, android-cursorloader

I have a question about some behavior in an AdapterView.OnItemClickListener that has me a bit flummoxed.

I have a ListView backed by a custom CursorAdapter. The Cursor is being managed by a LoaderManager. The ListView also has an OnItemClickListener. The data loads properly and the ListView is correctly populated - in this case with many items.

What I'm finding is that the *position* argument to *onItemClick* is 0-based relative to the items showing on the screen, not the entire list. So for example if I scroll down and select the first viewable item, I'll actually get the first item in the list (which is not visible) instead of the one I selected. When I use a debugger, I see that *position* actually has a value of 0 even though the item selected was much further down in the list.

What's odd is that this worked fine until I started using the LoaderManager.

I'm using the v4 support library.

If I do something like this:

```
public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View listItem, int position, long id ) {

    Cursor c = myListAdapter.getItem( parent.getFirstVisiblePosition() + position );

    // do stuff
```

Then I get the data I actually selected, but I somehow feel this is wrong. I shouldn't have to use *getFirstVisiblePosition()*.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: How is your listview's height set?  If you have it set to "wrap_content", it can cause some weird behavior, where it calls getView on a bunch of extra cells (usually the first few in my experience) to measure them.  It's probably not your bug, but worth a look.

Comment: Does it work if you use [`getItemAtPosition`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition(int)) from the AdapterView instead of going through the Adapter?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might be using the `convertView` parameter of the `getView()` method to recycle the views. Using this might be causing the issues here. Kindly try using an alternative and check whether the issue still exists or not